# Sprite follow multiple CGPath in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want `k` to follow multiple paths. I want it to finish p1 and then run p2. After it finishes p2, i want it to follow p3. How can I do this? Is there a handler that detects if the sprite finishes the path?

```
//k is my SKSpritenode

func followPath(path:CGPath,sprite:SKSpriteNode,speed:CGFloat){

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.followPath(path, speed: speed))

    }

followPath(p1, sprite: k, speed: 90)
followPath(p2, sprite: k, speed: 90)
followPath(p3, sprite: k, speed: 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list of actions into a sequence and then this sequence as one long actions itself.

Apologies, as I use Xamarin and C#, so my calls will look slightly different, but in essence, here's a simple example:

```
var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
var path = new CGPath();
path.AddRect(rect);
var moveOneDirection = SKAction.FollowPath(path, false, true, 5.0f);
var sequence = SKAction.Sequence(moveOneDirection, moveOneDirection.ReversedAction);

sprite.RunAction(SKAction.RepeatAction(sequence, 3));
```

This will make your sprite move along a rectangle, then back, and do this 3 times. Obviously, you can add many more paths!